# What's  the problem in this update command of GridView?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sqldatasource

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Dim constr As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"


Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdatedEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdated
        For Each myRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            'Find the checkbox
            Dim lab1 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
            Dim lab4 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label4"), Label)
            Try
                Using conn = New SqlConnection(constr)
                    Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
                        conn.Open()
                        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE a1_volvo SET travel = @travel WHERE travelid = @travelid"
                        cmd.CommandText = sql
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@travel", lab4.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@travelid", lab1.Text)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
```

**ERROR : Object reference is not set to the instance of object ..**

Comment: Do not shout - turn off caps lock

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the kine that throws the exception. You can debug your code to check the values or your variables.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to use a GridView is a lot easier than what you tried. This is in a .aspx file, not code-behind:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGV" DataSourceID="myDS" runat="server"/>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="myDS" SelectCommand="..." UpdateCommand="..." runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is either with

```
Dim lab1 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
```

or with

```
Dim lab4 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label4"), Label)
```

or with both.

Probably what happens is, when you assign your lab1 or lab4, it doesn't get any values, and then when you are trying to assign sql command parameter and giving value of `lab4.Text`, if lab4 itself is empty, it will throw ` Object reference is not set to the instance of object  exception.

But that's just a guess. In order to know forsure, you need to set a breakpoint, and debug your application. While debugging, check values of lab1 and lab4, after assigning it.

Hope this helps